# Conky 1.12.2 not showing graph borders (Ubuntu/Pop OS 22.04)

Tags: linux, ubuntu, debian, conky

I just started playing with Conky (v. 1.12.2), and everything is great except I cannot make it show graph borders. [(See screenshot)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/yTNi3.png) Borders appear only if I toggle outlines or shadows on, but I'd very much avoid it given the bad aesthetic result. My configuration file is at the bottom of the post (it is a modified version of one I found online); draw_graph_borders is set to True.

(There is also a weird "4m" text appearing on the graphs, visible in the screenshot: any idea?)

I am running a fresh install of Pop OS! (a lightly customized Ubuntu variant) 22.04, with its default desktop environment; my Huawei laptop has an Intel HD Graphics 620 card.

Thanks a lot for your help.
Massimo

```
conky.config = {
own_window_argb_visual = true,
own_window_argb_value = 170,
double_buffer = true,
alignment = 'top_right',
background = false,
border_width = 1,
cpu_avg_samples = 2,
default_color = 'white',
default_outline_color = 'white',
default_shade_color = 'white',
double_buffer = true,
draw_borders = false,
draw_graph_borders = true,
draw_outline = false,
draw_shades = false,
extra_newline = false,
font = 'DejaVu Sans Mono:size=12',
gap_x = 60,
gap_y = 60,
minimum_height = 5,
minimum_width = 5,
net_avg_samples = 2,
no_buffers = true,
out_to_console = false,
out_to_ncurses = false,
out_to_stderr = false,
out_to_x = true,
own_window = true,
own_window_class = 'Conky',
own_window_type = 'normal',
show_graph_range = true,
show_graph_scale = false,
stippled_borders = 0,
update_interval = 1.0,
uppercase = false,
use_spacer = 'none',
use_xft = true,
}

--stuff after 'TEXT' will be formatted on screen

conky.text = [[
${color grey}$nodename   linux-$kernel${alignr} ${time %T}

#${color grey}System:
${color grey} Battery:${color white} ${battery BAT1} 

${color grey} CPU Frequency:${color white} $freq_g ${color grey} ${color grey} CPUUsage:${color white} $cpu% ${cpubar} 
${color #000000} ${cpugraph cpu0 32,240 000000 7f8ed3} ${color #000000}${memgraph 32,240 000000 d37f00}
${color grey} RAM Usage:${color white} $mem/$memmax - $memperc% ${membar}
${color grey} Swap Usage:${color white} $swap/$swapmax - $swapperc% ${swapbar}
$hr
${color grey}Wifi:${color grey} ${color white}${wireless_essid wlp1s0} ${color grey}bitrate:${color white} ${wireless_bitrate wlp1s0}
${color grey} ${execi 120 iwconfig wlp1s0 | grep Link}
${color grey}Down:${color white} ${downspeed wlp1s0} k/s${color grey}${offset 80}Up:${color white} ${upspeed wlp1s0} k/s
${color #000000}${downspeedgraph wlp1s0 32,240 000000 7f8ed3} ${color #000000}${upspeedgraph wlp1s0 32,240 000000 8e7f00}
 ${color grey}Address: ${color white}${addr wlp1s0}${alignr} ${color grey}External IP:    $color${execi 1800  wget -q -O- http://ipecho.net/plain; echo}
 ${color grey}VPN Status: $color${execi 60 expressvpn status | head -1 | ansifilter}
$hr
${color grey}File Systems:
 ${color grey}/ ${color white}${fs_used /}/${fs_size /} ${color white}${fs_bar /}
 ${color grey}~ ${color white}${fs_used /home}/${fs_size /home} ${color white}${fs_bar /home}

${color grey}Name              PID     CPU%   MEM%
${color white} ${top name 1} ${top pid 1} ${top cpu 1} ${top mem 1}
${color white} ${top name 2} ${top pid 2} ${top cpu 2} ${top mem 2}
${color white} ${top name 3} ${top pid 3} ${top cpu 3} ${top mem 3}
${color grey}Mem usage
${color white} ${top_mem name 1} ${top_mem pid 1} ${top_mem cpu 1} ${top_mem mem 1}
${color white} ${top_mem name 2} ${top_mem pid 2} ${top_mem cpu 2} ${top_mem mem 2}
${color white} ${top_mem name 3} ${top_mem pid 3} ${top_mem cpu 3} ${top_mem mem 3}
$hr
${color grey}Local Weather:
${color white}${execi 1800 python3 /home/massimo/weather.py}
  
]]
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> I cannot make it show graph borders.

The `${color #000000}` cause black borders to be drawn on the black background. If I remove that color specification, I see the borders.

(I didn't see the *"4m" text*.)

Comment: Thanks!! For some reason I didn't notice that specification, I think I subconsciously thought it had to do with the background!